# Why do I get a missing references error asking for System.Runtime and System.Object

Tags: mvvm-light

VS2013 , new WPF/VB.NET project, using Framework 4.5.2, and NuGet MVVMLight Libraries Only.

```
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command
Public Class LoginViewModel
    Inherits ViewModelBase  '<-------------THIS LINE
End Class
```

Will Not Complile:
error a reference is required for System.Runtime and System.ObjectModel 
if added, then it works correctly.

These references are not shown in the available list when using the standard "add references" feature, but if I use the "error suggestions" on the above line of code it will add references in for me.

What am I doing wrong that I have to make these manual and seemingly unorthodox adjustments?

thanks
Josh

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with VS2015 RC. The error suggestions solution doesn't work for me, it opens the Add Reference dialog but there is no entry for System.Runtime.

Comment: I think you can browse for it, in a directory similar to Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a [known issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2971005), I downloaded the first package (328MB) linked in that KB article and after running the installer it resolved the error.

Update: Turns out this isn't working, I just received the error again after adding a new class to the project.

Comment: I installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack as suggested, but it did NOT fix the issue for me.    Note, I do not get the error in VS2015 Community (14.0.23107.0 D14REL).  I DO see the error in VS2013 (12.0.40629.00 Update 5).